# Как используя beautifulsoup извлечь значение атрибута тега

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

```html
<p id="plus" magazine_name="Supermarket" magazine_sort="jKZIRdGMXN" **name="Жевательная резинка DIROL 13,6гр Арбузная свежесть"** tid="eLPZRNbog6">+</p>
```

Мне нужно получить значение `name` (Жевательная резинка DIROL 13,6гр Арбузная свежесть),
но используя метод `text`, получаю только `+` (насколько я понял - искомое значение `name`, не является текстом).

Использую:

```py
product_name = soup.find(class_="tovar-schet").find("p") #и дальше ничего не получаю и не могу понять как вытащить "name"
```

Кусочек сохранённого html:

```html
<div class="tovar-schet" tid="eLPZRNbog6">
    <div id="minus" tid="eLPZRNbog6" price="39.9">−</div>      
    <div class="kol-vo" id="kol-voeLPZRNbog6">0</div>
    <p id="plus" tid="eLPZRNbog6" name="Жевательная резинка DIROL 13,6гр Арбузная свежесть" magazine_sort="jKZIRdGMXN" magazine_name="Supermarket">+</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

beautiful-soup позволяет напрямую обратится к атрибутам найденного элемента. В данном случае нам надо обратиться к атрибуту name, поэтому мы можем воспользоваться `element["name"]`

Для вашего примера:

```
product_name = soup.find(class_="tovar-schet").find("p")
print(product_name["name"])
```

Так же не стоит путать `element.name` и `element["name"]`. В первом случае получим название тэга (div, p и тд), во втором случае получим содержимое атрибута name.

Answer (score 0):

```
а как я могу получить данные в цикле?
#product_name = soup.find(class_="tovar-schet").find("p") #вытащил значение из тега по атрибуту
#product_price = soup.find("div", class_="tovar-price").text #вытащил цену

#пытался создавать переменную "data" с выводом на "data.append", но получается какая-то белиберда
for product in products:
    product_name = product.find("p")  # вытащил значение из тега по атрибуту
    product_price = product.text  # вытащил цену
    print(product_name["name"], product_price)

кусок кода:

    <div class="tovar">
                                <div class="image-tovar" tid="ewTGyaFPql" name_eng="zhevatelnaya-rezinka-dirol-13-6gr-ledyanaya-myata">
                                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/priceboximagesbucket/goods/7622210617828.jpeg ">  
                                </div>                                 
                                <div class="tovar-schet" tid="ewTGyaFPql">
                                    <div id="minus" tid="ewTGyaFPql" price="39.9">−</div>      
                                    <div class="kol-vo" id="kol-voewTGyaFPql">0</div>
                                    <p id="plus" tid="ewTGyaFPql" price="39.9" name="Жевательная резинка DIROL 13,6гр Ледяная мята 1/30шт" magazine_sort="jKZIRdGMXN">+</p>
                                </div>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите